# chained java.lang.SQLException instances vs. Throwable#getCause

Tags: java, jdbc

What are the semantics behind a "chain" of [SQLException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html) objects and how is this different from the similar (implicit) chain that's formed by the `getCause` method on the `Throwable` class?

Since a `SQLException` is also a `Throwable`, an instance of that class can have two such "chains:

- one defined by a sequence of `getNextException()` calls - till null is ultimately returned
- the other defined by a sequence of `getCause()` calls - till null is ultimately returned

... in such a case how would these two chains relate to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`SQLException.setNextException(Exception)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#setNextException%28java.sql.SQLException%29) and [`SQLException.getNextException()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#getNextException%28%29) allows for multiple distinct `SQLException`s to be reported back from a single method invocation. Those `SQLException`s are not each others cause.

The actual occurrence is pretty rare, but say that I execute a prepared insert statement with 2 parameters. One of those parameters is too long, and another is null while the column is `NOT NULL`. A database could (although I believe most databases won't) report both errors back to the driver. But as the `executeUpdate` method can only throw a single `SQLException`, these errors are chained together using `setNextException`. This then allows you to find out both error conditions

Also note that `SQLException` has an [`iterator()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html#iterator%28%29) method which allows you to iterate over each `SQLException` and their causes (ie: the current `SQLException`, all causes of the current `SQLException`, the next `SQLException` if any etc.

It is similar to the use of `getNextWarning()` for `SQLWarning` if multiple warnings occurred (either concurrent or sequentially), they are chained together. `SQLWarning` is not thrown, but made available on the object that generated the warning (eg [`Connection.getWarnings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#getWarnings%28%29), [`Statement.getWarnings()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings%28%29) etc). This method returns the first warning, and allows you to discover the additional warnings using `getNextWarning()`.

Comment: So you are saying that the SQLException#iterator method performs a depth first traversal of the Exception tree? Cause it's really a tree, as theoretically the `getCause` of a SQLException instance (at some depth) could return another SQLException, with its own chained exceptions. Now, I only wish for method to stringify all that exception tree both in deptn (like Apache lang3 ExceptionUtils#getStackTrace which keeps digging on the #getCause method) and in breadth (along the chained SQLExceptions) so I can log a single, all-encompassing `String` object.

Comment: @MarcusJuniusBrutus Looking at the sourcecode of [`SQLException`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/sql/SQLException.java?av=f#314), it will not iterate over the 'next SQLException chain' from a cause. It will only iterate over the chain of `getNextException` from the initial `SQLException` and over the cause chain of each `SQLException` in that initial chain.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's for historical reasons:

- `getNextException()` is there since jdbc was introduced with Java 1.1
- `getCause()` states it's there "since 1.4"

So `getNextException()` seems to be there for compatibility reasons, `getCause()` is the more recent and more general way to chain Exceptions.

Comment: It is not entirely the same `getNextException()` can also be used for multiple concurrent exceptions that are not necessarily each others cause (although the occurrence of that is pretty rare).